# Melhor maneira de capturar o progresso de um upload

Tags: javascript

Olá, gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de capturar o progresso de um upload utilizando o XMLHttpRequest .

Comment: o que seria o xhr?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Upload via XMLHttpRequest não conhecia. Pode dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você trabalha com o upload e com a `api` `XMLHttpRequest`, você tem acesso ao objeto `XMLHttpRequest.upload`. Com esse objeto, basta adicionar o evento `progress` para capturar o total de bytes que foram enviados e o total de bytes do arquivo.

Dessa forma podemos realizar o cálculo: `n = (total de bytes enviados * 100) / total de bytes do arquivo`

E para retornar um inteiro, utilizamos o método `Math.floor(n)`

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="file" /><br><br>
        <button>Send</button>

        <script>
            const inputFile = document.querySelector("input");
            const button = document.querySelector("button");
            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(progress) {
                if ( progress.lengthComputable ) {
                        console.log( Math.floor((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total) + "%" );
                }
            });

            button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);

                req.open("POST", "index3.php", true);
                req.send(formData);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```